# Hadoop concatenate files recursively maintaining directory structure

Tags: file, hadoop, path, filesystems, hdfs

I would like to add files of 2 directories under a single directory, also maintaining the directory structure.

i have directory 1 and directory 2, each with approx 80 subdirectories structured in the way shown below.

Directory 1 on HDFS:

- /user/hadoop/1/abc/file11
- /user/hadoop/1/def/file12
- /user/hadoop/1/ghi/file13
- /user/hadoop/1/jkl/file14
- /user/hadoop/1/mno/file15

Directory 2 on HDFS:

- /user/hadoop/2/abc/file26
- /user/hadoop/2/ghi/file27
- /user/hadoop/2/mno/file28

i want to combine file11 of dir 1 and file 26 of dir 2 to be present under a single directory, file 13 of dir 1 and dir 27 and so on.
Destination directory is directory 1.

The files that are to the added from dir 2 to dir 1 should match the path of subdirectory.

Desired Output:

- /user/hadoop/1/abc/file11 , /user/hadoop/1/abc/file26
- /user/hadoop/1/def/file12
- /user/hadoop/1/ghi/file13 , /user/hadoop/1/ghi/file27
- /user/hadoop/1/jkl/file14
- /user/hadoop/1/mno/file15 , /user/hadoop/1/mno/file28

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to copy /user/hadoop/1/abc/file11
and /user/hadoop/2/abc/file26
under same directory /user/hadoop/1/abc/? similarly others? what have you tried till now?

Comment: If you are okay with answer, flag-up "accepted by owner" and upvote as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting a unique file name for each file under directory 2 and adding to the right subdirectory under dir 1.
Following is the script:

```
for file in $(hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/2/* | grep -o -e "/user/hadoop/2/.*") ; do

subDir=$(echo $file | cut -d '/' -f 5)
fileName=$(echo $file | cut -d '/' -f 6)
uuid=$(uuidgen)
newFileName=$fileName"_"$uuid

    hadoop fs -cp $file /user/hadoop/1/$subDir/$newFileName
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html) API

You get `FileSystem` with below API

```
 final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

- **copy**

  public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS,
             Path[] srcs,
             FileSystem dstFS,
             Path dst,
             boolean deleteSource,
             boolean overwrite,
             Configuration conf)
                      throws IOException
  Throws:
  IOException

> This method Copy files between FileSystems.

- **Replace file**
  `FileUtil.replaceFile(File src, File target)` should also work

> see documentation for this method "Move the src file to the name specified by target."

In either case, you need to list your common folder **/user/hadoop/2/abc/** **/user/hadoop/1/abc/** by comparing after third slash character and if they are matching copy source to destination or develop logic according to your requirement(this I will leave it to you :-))

after copying to desired target : you can see them on the flow with below example method

```
/**
         * Method listFileStats.
         * 
         * @param destination
         * @param fs
         * @throws FileNotFoundException
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static void listFileStats(final String destination, final FileSystem fs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            final FileStatus[] statuss = fs.listStatus(new Path(destination));
            for (final FileStatus status : statuss) {
///below log are sl4j you can use other loggers..
                LOG.info("--  status {}    ", status.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Im getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:146)
I have both commons-logging-1.1.1.jar: and commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar in my bin/hadoop classpath

Comment: pls note that there is no relation between the question which was asked and this classnotfound error. This is related to your hadoop class path. while executing your java file.

Comment: Kindly could you elaborate more on the solution you provided please.
I would like to know how to check if dir 2's abc or ghi or mno are present in dir 1, i.e check until 3rd slash

Comment: regarding take that in a string for ex: str = "/a/d/c" use str.split("/");